# How can i Unmount a component in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component with different render depending on the step we are :

```
render(){

  ..some code to determine step ..

  return(
    {step == 1 && <Step1/>}
    {step == 2 && <Step2/>}
    {step == 3 && <Step3/>}
  )    
}

...
```

I can go through the step and sometime go back. When i go back from step 3 to 2, the component step 3 is not unmounted. I want it to be because i have some function that run on init that depends on configuration in step 2, so if a user change configuration in step 2 actually it does not change what i see in step 3 (and it should).

I have no idea how to unmount my component, if anyone know how I'll be glad to know ! Thanks in advance

Comment: From a quick glance, that logic should let React correctly mount and unmount each Step component properly. There's probably a bug somewhere else in your `render` or elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the state in your parent Component called 'step' and outsource your logic to determine step in a standalone method

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
       step: 1
   }
}

stepsHandle() {
    ..some code to determine step ..
}

render(){
  const step = this.state.step;
  return(
    {step == 1 && <Step1/>}
    {step == 2 && <Step2/>}
    {step == 3 && <Step3/>}
  )    
}
```

Comment: it's way better to use the state for that effectively, thanks. It's working now.

Comment: By the way, a cleaner way to implement this is to create a mapping dictionary/array, e.g .`const stepComponents = [Step1, Step2, Step3]; const StepComponent = stepComponents[this.state.step]; return <StepComponent />;`